# Close previous windows form when clicked other button

Tags: c#

i try to close windows form in mdiparent when i click other button, the result is when i click other button, it still appear from the back of new window. so how can i handle this?

```
private void btn_ic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    SelectIC ss = new SelectIC();
    ss.MdiParent = this;
    ss.Show();
    Detail aa = new Detail();
    aa.MdiParent = this;
    aa.Close();
    btn_ic.Enabled = false;
    btn_cat.Enabled = true;

}


private void btn_cat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    Detail aa = new Detail();
    aa.MdiParent = this;
    aa.Show();
    SelectIC ss = new SelectIC();
    ss.MdiParent = this;
    ss.Close();
    btn_cat.Enabled = false;
    btn_ic.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `new Detail()` doesn't give you the existing window - it creates a new window. If you want to affect a window you previously created, you need to keep a reference to it and interact with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making new instance of form and then closing it. That way you're not closing existing window but creating new (invisible) one and closing it. You should find existing window in collection of `MdiChildren` and then close it. Something like this:

```
private void btn_ic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    SelectIC ss = new SelectIC();
    ss.MdiParent = this;
    ss.Show();

    var detailForm = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(Detail));
    detailForm?.Close();

    btn_ic.Enabled = false;
    btn_cat.Enabled = true;

}

private void btn_cat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    Detail aa = new Detail();
    aa.MdiParent = this;
    aa.Show();

    var selectForm = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(SelectIC));
    selectForm?.Close();

    btn_cat.Enabled = false;
    btn_ic.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: sorry sir.. when i run code above, they give error.. the message " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."